# Compound Interest Program Will Not Calculate

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to get this program to work but for some reason it will not calculate the compounded interest. A little help would be appreciated. Note I did not finish the if statements for whatever value is entered into compoundInterestEditText field. I was hoping it would work just with what i have. The endValueEditText will not even update.

Main.java:

```
 package com.example.compoundinterest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.app.Activity;


public class Main extends Activity {

    //contants used when saving and restoring state
        private static final String CAPITAL_TOTAL = "CAPITAL_TOTAL";
        private static final String INTEREST_RATE = "INTEREST_RATE";
        private static final String YEARS_GROW = "YEARS_GROW";
        private static final String ANNUAL_ADDITION = "ANNUAL_ADDITION";
        private static final String COMPOUND_RATE = "COMPOUND_RATE";
        private static final String END_VALUE = "END_VALUE";

    //double values for calculations
    private double currentCapital;
    private double currentInterestRate;
    private double currentYearsToGrow;
    private double currentAnnualAddition;
    private double currentCompoundInterest;
    private double currentEndValue;

        //declare variables to be used
        private EditText capitalEditText;
        private EditText interestRateEditText;
        private EditText yearsToGrowEditText;
        private EditText annualAdditionEditText;
        private EditText compoundInterestEditText;
        private EditText endValueEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //check if app has been started or being restored from memory
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            currentCapital = 0.0;//initialize the capital amount to zero
            currentInterestRate = 0;//initialize the interest rate to zero
            currentYearsToGrow = 0;//initialize the years to grow to zero
            currentAnnualAddition = 0;//initialize the annual addition to zero
            currentCompoundInterest = 0;//initialize the interest rate to zero
            currentEndValue = 0;//initialize the end value to zero
        }//end if

        else//app is being restored from memory, not executed from scratch
        {
            //initialize the capital amount to saved amount
            currentCapital = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CAPITAL_TOTAL);

            //initialize interest rate to saved amount
            currentInterestRate = savedInstanceState.getInt(INTEREST_RATE);

            //initialize years to grow amount to saved amount
            currentYearsToGrow = savedInstanceState.getInt(YEARS_GROW);

            //initialize annual addition amount to saved amount
            currentAnnualAddition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ANNUAL_ADDITION);

            //initialize compound interest rate amount to saved amount
            currentCompoundInterest = savedInstanceState.getInt(COMPOUND_RATE);

            //initialize end value amount to saved amount
            currentEndValue = savedInstanceState.getInt(END_VALUE);

        }//end else




        //get references to EditText fields
        capitalEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capitalEditText);
        interestRateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interestRateEditText);
        yearsToGrowEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yearsToGrowEditText);
        annualAdditionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.annualAdditionEditText);
        compoundInterestEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.compoundInterestEditText);
        endValueEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endValueEditText);

        endValueEditText.addTextChangedListener(endValueEditTextWatcher);




    }//end of method onCreate


    //function for updating the values as the numbers entered by user are changed
    private void updateValue() {

        if(currentCompoundInterest == 1) {


            double finalCalculation = currentCapital * (1 + currentInterestRate);
            endValueEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalCalculation));
        }

        else if(currentCompoundInterest ==2) {

        }

        else if(currentCompoundInterest==3) {

        }

        else if(currentCompoundInterest==4) {

        }



    }//end of updateValue() function


    //main function to aid in updating the user input
    private TextWatcher endValueEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            //convert billEditText's text to a double
            try {
                currentCapital = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                currentInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                currentYearsToGrow = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                currentAnnualAddition = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                currentCompoundInterest = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                currentEndValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            }//end try
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                currentCapital = 0.0;//default if an exception occurs
                currentInterestRate = 0.0;//default if an exception occurs
                currentYearsToGrow = 0.0;//default if an exception occurs
                currentAnnualAddition = 0.0;//default if an exception occurs
                currentCompoundInterest = 0.0;//default if an exception occurs
                currentEndValue = 0.0;//default if an exception occurs
            }//end catch

            //run updateValue Function
            updateValue();

        }//end of onTextChanged inner onTextChanged





        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }//end method afterTextChanged

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }//end method beforeTextChanged

    };//end of endValueEditTextWatcher

}//end of Compound Interest function
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >






        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionsTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Enter Value to be borrowed or invested:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/capitalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Capital" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/capitalEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/interestRateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Interest Rate (%)" />




        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/interestRateEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yearsToGrowTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Years To Grow" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/yearsToGrowEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annualAdditionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Annual Addition" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/annualAdditionEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compoundInterestTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Compound Interest" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/compoundInterestEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

    </TableRow>



    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="50dp" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/endValueTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="End Value" />






        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/endValueEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
10-19 15:30:59.251: E/CircleShortcutWidget(641): density = 320
10-19 15:30:59.251: E/CircleShortcutWidget(641): pkg name =com.android.contacts, activityName=com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity
10-19 15:30:59.251: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): mIconWidth =0
10-19 15:30:59.251: D/PhoneStatusBar(777): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK* HOME RECENT CLOCK* >
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): BitmapDrawable
10-19 15:30:59.261: E/CircleShortcutWidget(641): pkg name =com.android.mms, activityName=com.android.mms.ui.ConversationComposer
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): mIconWidth =0
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): BitmapDrawable
10-19 15:30:59.261: E/CircleShortcutWidget(641): pkg name =com.sec.android.widgetapp.diotek.smemo, activityName=com.sec.android.widgetapp.q1_penmemo.MemoListActivity
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): mIconWidth =0
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): BitmapDrawable
10-19 15:30:59.261: E/CircleShortcutWidget(641): pkg name =com.sec.android.app.camera, activityName=com.sec.android.app.camera.Camera
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): mIconWidth =0
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/CircleShortcutWidget(641): BitmapDrawable
10-19 15:30:59.261: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.271: D/CircleLockScreen(641): onRefreshBatteryInfo() showPatteryInfo: true pluggedIn: true batteryLevel: 76
10-19 15:30:59.271: D/ClockWidget(641): refreshTime()
10-19 15:30:59.281: D/ClockWidget(641): TTS Message = It is 3 : 30 PM, Friday, October 19
10-19 15:30:59.281: W/LockPatternKeyguardView(641): Couldn't find transport control widget
10-19 15:30:59.281: D/ClockWidget(641): refreshTime()
10-19 15:30:59.291: D/ClockWidget(641): TTS Message = It is 3 : 30 PM, Friday, October 19
10-19 15:30:59.291: D/ClockWidget(641): isServiceEnable = false cityId = cityId:347628
10-19 15:30:59.291: D/ClockWidget(641): Weather Demon is not running, Set visibility to GONE
10-19 15:30:59.301: E/LockPatternKeyguardView(641): mResetWakeLock.release()
10-19 15:30:59.311: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.321: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(641): handleClockVisibilityChanged()
10-19 15:30:59.321: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): adjustStatusBarLocked: mShowing=true mHidden=false isSecure=false --> flags=0x1200000
10-19 15:30:59.331: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.331: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(641): handleClockVisibilityChanged()
10-19 15:30:59.331: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): adjustStatusBarLocked: mShowing=true mHidden=false isSecure=false --> flags=0x1200000
10-19 15:30:59.331: D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(641): manageDisableList what=0x1200000 pkg=android
10-19 15:30:59.331: D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(641): manageDisableList what=0x1200000 pkg=android
10-19 15:30:59.351: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x439ad000 size:3674112 fd:11
10-19 15:30:59.351: D/memalloc(641): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x65c51000 size:3674112 offset:0 fd:386
10-19 15:30:59.371: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.371: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.371: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.381: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
10-19 15:30:59.381: D/memalloc(331): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x449ea000 size:1884160 fd:35
10-19 15:30:59.381: D/memalloc(331): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x446ca000 size:3276800 fd:37
10-19 15:30:59.381: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(777): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
10-19 15:30:59.391: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x446ca000 size:3485696 fd:35
10-19 15:30:59.401: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x44abd000 size:3768320 fd:37
10-19 15:30:59.401: D/memalloc(777): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x6022d000 size:3485696 offset:0 fd:103
10-19 15:30:59.411: D/memalloc(10083): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ce44000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:52
10-19 15:30:59.441: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.441: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1158>: RGBX_8888
10-19 15:30:59.441: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.491: D/dalvikvm(777): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2139K, 20% free 21315K/26595K, paused 68ms
10-19 15:30:59.562: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x4563a000 size:3485696 fd:48
10-19 15:30:59.562: D/memalloc(777): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x60580000 size:3485696 offset:0 fd:106
10-19 15:30:59.562: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.562: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
10-19 15:30:59.562: D/memalloc(331): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x427ad000 size:3276800 fd:45
10-19 15:30:59.562: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.562: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.562: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.572: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.572: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x421c7000 size:94208 fd:45
10-19 15:30:59.572: D/memalloc(331): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x42312000 size:163840 fd:36
10-19 15:30:59.572: D/memalloc(777): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dd63000 size:94208 offset:0 fd:100
10-19 15:30:59.572: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.582: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19405(2764) createSurface (1440x1280),-1 flag=20000
10-19 15:30:59.582: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.582: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1088>: RGB_565
10-19 15:30:59.602: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19406(2765) createSurface (720x2560),-1 flag=20000
10-19 15:30:59.612: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x427ad000 size:3674112 fd:36
10-19 15:30:59.612: D/memalloc(641): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x65fd2000 size:3674112 offset:0 fd:395
10-19 15:30:59.612: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19407(2766) createSurface (1440x1280),-1 flag=20000
10-19 15:30:59.632: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19408(2767) createSurface (720x2560),-1 flag=20000
10-19 15:30:59.632: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.632: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
10-19 15:30:59.632: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.632: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19403 Removed idx=11 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.632: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19405 Removed idx=7 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.632: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19403 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.632: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19406 Removed idx=7 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.632: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19405 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.642: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19407 Removed idx=7 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.642: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19406 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.642: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19408 Removed idx=7 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.642: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19407 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.642: W/SurfaceFlinger(331): id=19408 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=5
10-19 15:30:59.652: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.652: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x4598d000 size:3768320 fd:55
10-19 15:30:59.652: D/memalloc(10083): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d2dc000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:59
10-19 15:30:59.662: D/KeyguardViewMediator(641): setHidden false
10-19 15:30:59.672: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.672: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1158>: RGBX_8888
10-19 15:30:59.722: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x44e55000 size:3485696 fd:64
10-19 15:30:59.722: D/memalloc(777): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x60a9d000 size:3485696 offset:0 fd:109
10-19 15:30:59.722: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:30:59.722: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
10-19 15:30:59.992: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(641): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
10-19 15:30:59.992: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(641): handleTimeUpdate
10-19 15:30:59.992: W/AlarmManager(641): FACTORY_ON= 0
10-19 15:31:00.002: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(777): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
10-19 15:31:00.002: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(777): updateClock :3:31 PM
10-19 15:31:00.002: D/STATUSBAR-DateView(777): updateClock :10/19/2012
10-19 15:31:00.052: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:31:00.052: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
10-19 15:31:00.062: D/ClockWidget(641): refreshTime()
10-19 15:31:00.072: D/ClockWidget(641): TTS Message = It is 3 : 31 PM, Friday, October 19
10-19 15:31:00.092: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x45d25000 size:3674112 fd:71
10-19 15:31:00.092: D/memalloc(641): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x66353000 size:3674112 offset:0 fd:400
10-19 15:31:00.102: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:31:00.112: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
10-19 15:31:00.142: E/SMD(327): DCD ON
10-19 15:31:00.152: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x4614b000 size:3768320 fd:74
10-19 15:31:00.152: D/memalloc(10083): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d674000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:62
10-19 15:31:00.162: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:31:00.162: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1158>: RGBX_8888
10-19 15:31:00.763: D/BatteryService(641): update start
10-19 15:31:00.763: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(641): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-19 15:31:00.763: D/BatteryService(641): level:76 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 4138 temperature: 289 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303135 invalid charger:0
10-19 15:31:00.763: D/ThermistorObserver(641): mBatteryBRForAMOLED : onReceive() : newTemperature : 289
10-19 15:31:00.773: E/MTPJNIInterface(6119): In MTPJNIINterface onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(641): handleBatteryUpdate
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/memalloc(331): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x42269000 size:94208 fd:77
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/memalloc(331): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x4233a000 size:163840 fd:61
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/memalloc(777): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dd95000 size:94208 offset:0 fd:52
10-19 15:31:00.773: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
10-19 15:31:00.773: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(331): <GetImageAttributes:1088>: RGB_565
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(777): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(777): onReceive() - level:76
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(777): onReceive() - plugged:2
10-19 15:31:00.773: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(777): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
10-19 15:31:01.113: E/MP-Decision(1348): DOWN Ld:59 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.000000 seq:196.000000
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: You posted lot of content, but forgot to clearly explain "not working".

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting some error?

Comment: I did say what was not working. I said the endValueEditText (which is the final compounded calculation is not showing any value).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you receive a stack overflow exception, because `setText()` calls `onTextChanged()` which calls `updateValues()` which calls `setText()` which calls... (over and over).  Simply add a boolean to your TextWatcher:

```
private TextWatcher endValueEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    boolean update = false;
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        update = !update;
        if(!update)
            return;

        ...
    }
}
```

---

But I think you have created a strange user interface: only when the user types a value into `endValueEditText` will `updateValues()` be run. I think you should create a Button labeled "Calculate Interest" and read the EditText values in this Button's OnClickListener instead.  You should also change `endValueEditText` to a TextView since the user call really change this value.

Comment: Yes I agree, I have been following a similar example in a book and I have been trying to implement my own version (above). I agree a button for calculating is much easier but I have already done that. Thanks for your input. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: If you think any answer (or question) is useful you should click the up arrow to let everyone know. And if this answer solved your question please click the checkmark. If it didn't let me know if I can answer a more specific question on this.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. the endValueEditText field is still not showing any value as I enter values into the other fields.

Comment: Well "it did not work" is too vague for me to help you. What did you try and what is the error? (Post the LogCat in your question.)

Comment: I am new to Android. I apologize but my LogCat is blank. I never know why it does this sometimes. Really annoying. Nothing shows even with no filters.

Comment: Yea, that happens to me usually when I change devices or emulators. In Eclipse, try opening the "Devices" window and (re)selecting the device you are working with.

Comment: ok got the Log to show stuff but none of it pertains to the application running. I set the filter to debug.